# Windows Server 2008 Enterprise edition (cluster's ip address)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, website, cluster, fault-tolerance

My question is first of all for guys who had experience with Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition. As i found i can bake cluster (Failover Cluster Nodes). This cluster gives me one ip adress. So question: can i bind this virtual ip address to my website's domain address (for example http://example.com -> cluster ip address) for fault tolerance?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So question: can i bind this virtual
>   ip address to my website's domain
>   address (for example
>   http://example.com -> cluster ip
>   address) for fault tolerance?

Yes. This is exactly how it works - the currently active node will use the IP, so if you bind the IP to your side (and set up the rest corerrectly) this allows failover.

That said, it is a bad technolgoy for clustering websites. Better use NLB and balance (active / active). Clustering is a good choice - for active / passive nodes, but a website can be active / active.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do just that.

Comment: thank you for answer! Tell me please: as i understood this cluster's virtual ip address will be visible from internet? across network?

Comment: It depends if the VIP is a real external address, if so then sure you can expose that directly, if not you'll need to NAT it via your router - I'd suggest this anyway to be honest.